# Properties of the expectations operator

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

What is the name of the property of some function, $G(x)$, such that $\mathbb{E}[G(x)]=G(\mathbb{E}[x])$? Thank you.

Comment: I am not aware if this is a named property. You could say $G,\mathbb E$ commute. Note that this property is always true if $G(x)$ is of the form $ax+b,a,b\in\mathbb R$ i.e. $G(x)$ is linear.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) the statement is true ONLY if $g$ is linear.

In fact, for $g$ convex,

$$g(\mathbb{E}[X]) \leq\mathbb{E}[g(X)] $$

Comment: Equality in Jensen's inequality holds, according to the article, iff $X$ is constant a.s. or $g$ is a.s. equal to an affine function, but even that doesn't answer the question as it assumes $g$ is convex. Does the equality $g(\mathbb{E}[X])=\mathbb{E}[g(X)]$ already imply $g$ is convex?